# Python: Read file with negative number

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I was trying to read a .txt file and append it into a list inside a list, but I had encounter this problem.

**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'**

In which my code are like this:

```
def readfiles(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    matrix=[]
    tem=[]
    for i in range(len(content)):
       tem=[]
       content[i] = content[i].replace('\n','')
       content[i] = content[i].replace(',', '')
       for j in range(len(content[i])):
           tem.append(int(content[i][j]))
       matrix.append(tem)

    return matrix
```

but if i replace the **tem.append(int(content[i][j]))** to **tem.append(content[i][j])**

the list appear to be different which somehow look like this:

[['3', '-', '2', '1'], ['4', '-', '1', '0'], ['0', '2', '1']]

I wanted my function to read negative value from a file. Can anyone help with this ?

my .txt file look like this:

```
3,-2,1
4,-1,0
0,2,1
```

Comment: Why are you iterating over the characters in each line? Also, a side note: Don't iterate over `range(len(...))`, ever. Can you give an example of how your file looks like?

Comment: Could you edit the question to include a sample of what your text file looks like?

Comment: @MartinEvans I had attach a sample of text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that this would work:

```
def readfiles(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [[int(num) for num in line.split(",")] for line in f]
```

The problem you're having is that you're iterating over your line (which is a string), which gets you individual characters rather than "things between commas":

Let's say the current line (`content[i]`) is `"3,-2,1"`.
After this:

```
content[i] = content[i].replace(',', '')
```

`content[i]` is now `"3-21"`. How is it supposed to know what your numbers are? Iterating over that string gives you `"3", "-", "2", "1"`, where `"-"` causes the exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

If you have for example a string like this:

`numbers = "-6, 3, -3, 18"`

You always can do this:

`print [int(n) for n in numbers.split(',')]`

To get:

`[-6, 3, -3, 18]`

Maybe you need change the way to process your file, please add a extrat to show us how the numbers are in it.